# Encoding problems with Codeigniter and Sql Server using ODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, utf-8, odbc

Ok, this is the typical charset encoding problem between SQL Server and PHP. So I'll cut to the chase:

I'm using ODBC to connect to a Sql Server 2012 database. Here is the database configuration:

```
$db['odbc']['hostname'] = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=siadcon;';
$db['odbc']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['odbc']['password'] = 'sa';
$db['odbc']['database'] = 'siadcon';
$db['odbc']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['odbc']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['odbc']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['odbc']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['odbc']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['odbc']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['odbc']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['odbc']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['odbc']['swap_pre'] = '';
```

I have a table (`TABLE`) which contains special characters in the `NAME` field, which is a `NVARCHAR(30)`. The data:

```
ID  NAME
1   Marín
2   Other
```

My problem is when I do a simple query like:

```
$this->db->where('ID', '1');
$query = $this->db->get('TABLE');
```

I get this:

```
["ID"]=> string(2) "1" ["NAME"]=> string(5) "Mar�n"
```

I'm trying to avoid using `utf_encode/utf_decode` on every query, so I've tried a lot of things in order to properly configure things to get the correct encoding, but nothing seems to work for me.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Same problem when I try to make an insert from Codeigniter (using `$this->db->insert`). I've tried to insert "Tést", but in the SQLServer database I see "TÃ©st".

Comment: I'm giving up. I think I'm going to modify the ActiveRecord  insert(), update(), get()... methods.

Comment: have you found a solution on that?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I gave up.